# AngularJS: open and close DOM element during different cycles of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I wonder if it is possible to open DOM element during first cycle of ng-repeat and close it during the second. Let's talk about some list of element, and I want to output it by 2 (or may be 3, 4... it does not matter) in a row. So result html will be like this:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- add this line during 1sr cycle -->
   <div class="element">...element1...</div>
   <div class="element">...element2...</div>
</div> <!-- add this line during 2nd cycle -->
<div class="row"> <!-- add this line during 3rd cycle -->
   <div class="element">...element3...</div>
   <div class="element">...element4...</div>
</div><!-- add this line during 4th cycle -->
```

The main problem that ng-repeat does not allows me to put line `<div class="row">` on first cycle and put closing `</div>` on second cycle. ng-repeat add both of them during every cycle. Is it possible to find some workaround for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with ng-repeat. You have to either prepare the data structure in your controller (multi-dimensional array) or write a custom directive that would take and additional parameter of how many elements of the array take for the current iteration.

UPD: You can use lodash' chunk function to split the array into smaller arrays https://lodash.com/docs#chunk

Comment: Thanks, that is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can't output only half an element (e.g. the opening tag without the closing tag) in one repeat cycle.

You can however do different things in one cycle based on the `$index` property, like showing or hiding a specific element in the first cycle ($index: 0).

Alternatively, have a look at `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to output more than one element in a cycle. More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: But index based way does not help also: it still will output both open and close tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have found simple solution out of the box in angularJs:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="element in elements" ng-if="$index%2==0">
    <div class="element" ng-repeat="element in elements|limitTo:2:$index">...</div>
</div>
```

It will output 2 elements in a row, if you need more, you should adjust ng-if and limitTo argument.